# Call javascript function in for loop code-behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a js function that creates nav-tabs dynamically like this:

```
    function newTab(i) {

         for (var x = 0; x<i; x++ ){
             var nextTab = $('#tabs li').size() + 1;

             // create the tab
             $('<li><a href="#tab' + nextTab + '" data-toggle="tab">Tab ' + nextTab + '</a></li>').appendTo('#tabs');

             // create the tab content
             $('<div class="tab-pane" id="tab' + nextTab + '">tab' + nextTab + ' content</div>').appendTo('.tab-content');
         }
     };
```

I send the `i` parameter from my code behind

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim dtAreas As New DataTable
    Dim i As Integer 

    dtAreas = EvaRH.GetAreas
    i = dtAreas.Rows.Count - 1

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "Tab1", "newTab('" & i & "')", True)

End Sub
```

This is working fine, however I would like to set the tabs names to the ones I have on my Areas dataset, so first I changed my JS function to this:

```
function newTab() {

         var nextTab = $('#tabs li').size() + 1;

         // create the tab
         $('<li><a href="#tab' + nextTab + '" data-toggle="tab">Tab ' + nextTab + '</a></li>').appendTo('#tabs');

         // create the tab content
         $('<div class="tab-pane" id="tab' + nextTab + '">tab' + nextTab + ' content</div>').appendTo('.tab-content');
 };
```

And tried to create the tabs calling this function multiple times on a `for loop` from code behind:

```
    For i = 0 To dtAreas.Rows.Count - 1
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "tab" & i.ToString, "newrTab()", True)
    Next
```

But its not working, doesnt gives me any errors neither creates any tabs.
I have tried setting the js key value static, but didnt worked, also tried this two:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "tab" & i.ToString, "newTab()", True)
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Me.GetType(), "tab" & i.ToString, "newTab()", True)
```

I have also tried replacing the `&` with `+` with no succes

Comment: Your `newTab` expects parameter `i` which is not sent so it has `undefined` value.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev it was a type on the second function... sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client scripts and server code cannot be mixed this way. Javascript only runs on the browser and the only way it can communicate with your backend script is via AJAX (or some other network) calls.

Instead, have your server render out the HTML for the tabs with the names, as well as the tab panes with their respective content, then have your script find those tabs (based on the `data` attributes) and turn them into dynamic navigation. This will be better for SEO since even if javascript is disabled, your site content is still visible.

Comment: so basically with js its not possible? I know I could create the tabs on HTML, but was hoping to create them dynamically depending on the number of Areas that currently exists, so if in the future an Area is added or removed, it will create/remove that tag, without the need to change it on HTML, hope I made myself clear..

Comment: You have that information on the server so you can create more or less panels and then just have your script wrap however many are created. There are plenty of jquery plugins that would make wrapping a bunch of divs and converting them to tabs very trivial. something like `$('.panels').tabs()`

Comment: I think I understand you... lol, Im quite new to all this, will look into that thanks!

Comment: The idea is to let your server, with all the information, render out the static html, then have JQuery progressively enhance it by wrapping it and making it dynamic. Again, look for some jquery plugins first since plenty exist that do exactly what you want. Then, it's just a matter of satisfying the format of the HTML from your server.